# Play video using HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

Hi i need to display video in all the browsers using html5.

I am uploading the file and creating html structure and it plays only mp4 format video, but not other uploaded formats, and i use command line to convert files but the converted files doesn't play in video tag.

For conversion I use `ffmpeg` video conversion from one to `webm` format. Conversion works, but viedos don't play.

Please find me `ffmpeg` code, which converts all videos to `webm`, so i can play the converted video using html5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, http://caniuse.com/webm has some clear information about which browsers can use webm. I disagree with mp4 & ogv -> should be mp4 and webm.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Here is the command line.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -c:v libvpx -g 52 -b:v 4000k \ 
-maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -force_key_frames 00:00:00.000 \
-f webm -c:a libvorbis -b:a 128k movie.webm
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i used your above code and executed in command prompt but i got this error.                                                                            
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-c:v'

Comment: then you are probably using an older version of ffmpeg. try this: ffmpeg -i movie.mov -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm movie.webm

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but when i executed your code i got this errror. "Unknown input or output format: webm" what does this mean when m using the code : - 
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm output.webm

Comment: can any one tell me what should be the correct output format if we are converting from mp4 to webm, if i use .web  it says invalid output format.

Comment: It means that your version of ffmpeg was not compiled with libvpx.

Comment: I have downloaded the zip file and after extracting the files , where should i add the extracted files. These are the folders already available in my support files (bin,doc,include,lib,licenses,preset,tmp). so where do you suggest me to include the files.

Comment: You should follow these instructions.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide
But without knowing what system you are using I can't really help you. Maybe you should ask your provider.

Comment: I am using a windows platform, and to execute commands i use command prompt change to support file ffmpeg drive which is on machine and run the command. It's a windows 32bit machine.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a windows user and have no idea how to help you. This static ffmpeg build may be what you need though: http://ffmbc.googlecode.com/files/FFmbc-0.7rc7-win32-120705.zip

Comment: Hi, denjello i am facing problem in finding correct ffmpeg for the linux server, can you post me helpful link. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best choice i think, use 2 types of video.
`Ogg` and `mp4`

So in all browsers it will work

Example:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

you can look at the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)